# What API blueprint renderer can generate a three-column html file for API documentation purpose?

Tags: rendering, template-engine, blueprint

Here's the API doc of Stripe: https://stripe.com/docs/api
They seem to be using a three-columns template.
I am wondering whether they use some API blueprint renderer (markdown-to-html type of script) to generate it, similarly to Aglio: https://github.com/danielgtaylor/aglio

If they don't use any renderer, what other types of API blueprint renderers exist out there?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Stripe uses an in house doc generation tool, but Slate (https://github.com/tripit/slate) is a tool modeled off of Stripe's documentation. It looks quite similar and may be what you're looking for. I haven't used it myself so unfortunately I can't tell you much more.

If you want to stick to API Blueprint markdown flavor then check out apiary (http://apiary.io) as an alternative to aglio. It's not the three column layout but it is nice looking.

Comment: But Slate isn't an API Blueprint render, it just does plain Markdown. Also Apiary appears to be a public hosted solution, not a simple rendering tool.